# How to update SharePoint Online Managed Metadata from another application

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, managed-metadata

I would like to create a script on a server that does a daily update of a Managed Metadata term store item.

Is it possible to programatically update the SharePoint Online term store from a script hosted somewhere else? via the REST API or the like?

I cannot find any documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no Update method to update the managed metadata term store programmatically.

We can create group and get group, termsets and terms programmatically.

More references:

[TermStore members.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj164588(v=office.15))

[O365 - Programmatically Create New Term Store Management In SharePoint Online – CSOM.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/o365-programmatically-create-new-term-store-management-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: This seems rather odd that you can create but not update - what if you have source metadata that lives in another system that you need to sync with managed metadata in Sharepoint online? is there not a third party tool or the like if this is not possible via code.

Comment: Amy_MSFT since update is not available, would it be possible to do a delete then create? or would this break the Lists/Libraries/Content Types that depend on the managed metadata field?